# Font baseline is different in Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: css, cross-browser

I was reading about CSS font baselines all day and came up with a very simple example that produces different baselines in Chrome vs Firefox: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjAoGN)

```css
html {
  font-size: 10px;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.text {
  background-color: orange;
  font-size: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  line-height: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="text">
  My text &#220;
</div>
```

Chrome Version 53.0.2785.116 (64-bit): 
[image: Chrome]

Firefox 45.3.0:
[image: Firefox]

I'm using Mac OS 10.11.6.

## Is this some inherent browser difference that can't be solved nicely with CSS? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Both the snippet and the codepen look identical in both browsers on my machine. But I did notice you haven't stated a font family in the CSS, so... are you absolutely, positively certain that the screenshots are made using the exact same font?

Comment: They are done on the code I've posted. The font looks identical to my eye...

Comment: Although specifying "font-family: "Times New Roman";" fixes the issue. But the font is the same... Weird.

Comment: Some fonts look eerily similar, yes. Apart from metrics, number of glyphs etc.

Comment: I've noticed this too, it's especially apparent in a demo I made for a lib that strokes text: https://inorganik.github.io/strokeText.js/ . Some fonts like Times render at the right baselines in Firefox, most don't.